# Shiny app : `shinyjs` parse error, but script works as `script` tag

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I made a simple Shiny app with a video stream (if it works, using the laptop camera ). The entire Javascript is:

```
const player = document.getElementById('player');

const constraints = {
    video: true
};

// Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
 .then((stream) => {
   player.srcObject = stream;
});
```

If I wrap this in a shiny app like this,

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML('<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>'),
  tags$script(HTML(<<<CODE ABOVE>>>))
)
server <- function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

it works fine.

If instead I use the `shinyjs` package, place the Javascript in its own file 'startvid.js', and make the app like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML('<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>'),

  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(script = "www/startvid.js")
)
```

I get a Syntax error on parse:

`Error: shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: SyntaxError: Unexpected token >.`

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you have `=>` in the code, I think that could be the reason.

For me replacing line

```
var vector_out_it = Array.from(table_data, x => x[0]);
```

with lines

```
var vector_out_it = [];
for(it = 0; it < table_data.length; it ++) {vector_out_it.push(table_data[it][0])}
```

solved the problem

PS For some reason my shiny server has difficulties with js fat array operators (see 
https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/ for description)

It may depend on the system configuration because for me `extendShinyjs` works well locally (only after app deployment I got error desribed by you:

```
Warning: Error in : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: SyntaxError: Unexpected token >.
```

Comment: But my code does not include that line, it includes: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
 .then((stream) =>`

Comment: Yes but im particular there is " =>" and IMO there the problem lies.

Comment: I've just pasted part of my code where I've used "=>" After removing it worked :)